# Singleton pattern - Why would we need to check about initialization of mutable variable twice?

Tags: synchronization, thread-safety, critical-section

The thread will enter the synchronized code only when the condition `uniqueInstance == null` sets to true, so what is the need to check it again inside the critical section?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because in between the check and the synchronized call you could have been interrupted by another process which acquired the semaphore, wrote to the singleton, and quit.  There's a possibility that you'll overwrite the value that the other process already initialized unless you check again.

On the other hand, if you make the whole method synchronized, you pay the cost of synchronization on every call to the singleton rather than the first call only. It's better to check twice.

Comment: Ah, now I understand - you mean to say that mutex works for "threads" only, but some other "process" can ruin the things in between?

Comment: and in that case can't we use semaphore and mutex - both - there?

Comment: A thread with a higher priority can wake up at any time. There's no difference between that and a process. Both can interrupt you and set the singleton before you do.

Comment: But, the thread with the higher priority won't get into the mutex lock section to set the variable?

Comment: No if you have a mutex. But there's a cost to acquiring a mutex and the point of double check locking is to avoid the cost of acquiring the lock (whether it's a mutex, semaphore or synchronized) in the 99.9% of the cases where you don't need it (reading the singleton) while keeping it in the 0.1% of the times when you do (when the singleton is uninitialized). This requires a cheap test, a lock and another test to make sure you didn't get interrupted before you locked.

Comment: @Simberon You mean "you could have been interrupted by another thread", not "process"

Comment: To be clear, the first if check is an optimization and does not make the method more thread-safe. Just starting with the synchronize block and doing the if check inside that will be perfectly thread-safe, but forces you to incur the cost of synchronizing on every singleton access rather than only before the singleton has been initialized.